# Can't install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server On Windows 11

Tags: sql, windows-installer, odbc, ssms

i want install SSMS 19.1
this is stuck like picture

[image]

the problem for "microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" cant install
i download it manually and try install it but this error appear
[image]

Comment: `1.` Cancel that and then ensure the installer is copied to Windows 11 local file server and then right click on it and install elevated as administrator. `2.` If you have antivirus of endpoint security on the client workstation, try disabling it and then reinstalling again from the local file system elevated as administrator. `3.` Try pointing to the path which the SSMS installer is rather than `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Package~` and see if that helps.

Comment: 1.installer just copy odbc 17 installer in temp and stop for install it  .... (installer freeze)

Comment: For response you just `#1` you responded to, are you downloading the installer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#download-for-windows and here [these] --> https://i.imgur.com/tfr6dKH.png in particular. Try to redownload and see what happens for the x64 bit version. Try to install the x64 version of 18 reboot, retry SSMS install. Still pending your responses to previously mentioned `#2` and `#3`—don't forget those. Also ensure you have elevated admin access credential as needed for installers to work fully.

Comment: #2 don't work and #3 don't work ... thanks for your help.

Comment: According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-operating-systems), the ODBC from version 17.9 and newer is compatible with Windows 11 (https://i.imgur.com/Cuys6iY.png). If you upgraded or have some other version installed that is older, try to uninstall it, then reinstall the latest version of ODBC 17 with a fresh download. Try disabled AV or EndPoint protections and lastly is all else fails, try a Windows 11 repair install and then try to install a compatible version afterwards.

Comment: i downlaod fresh ODBC installer version 17.10.4 and try install it ... but it need ODBC version 17.0.62207 like picture in main question post ... i think i dont find this version in microsoft page ... how can i find it ?

Comment: Then that is your problem as per the comment above and the screen shot as listed here I also provided: https://i.imgur.com/Cuys6iY.png, ODBC version `17.0.62207` is NOT compatible with Windows 11. The solution is to install a version that is compatible. This means `17.0.62207` will not work with Windows 11 and you will have to use version `17.9` or newer.  Let me know if you want me to write this all up as an answer, but that's what's going on here. I'm not see that version in the question of the pic on the main post either, that key detail is missing from your question, thanks for providing!